# Create image in Python from C pointer

Tags: python, c++

Without giving you all details (DLL, wrapper C and code C++), I am using the  **OpenCV** library in my DLL to perform some operations on images. For now, I am using four methods of this library : `threshold`, `adaptivethreshold`, `filter2D` and `GaussianBlur`. I succeeded to recreate image from the function which return the result of the `threshold` method but from the other I have some shifts (different for each methods and different values of the same parameter on the same method). My DLL return an `unsigned short *` pointer because I deal with uint8/16 images.

Moreover, if I call these same functions from my DLL but with a C++ program, I get correct images without shifts.

For example, on Python, I recreate the image from the pointer return by the `filter2D` function using :

```
# Load the DLL in memory
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("PathOfMyDll.dll")

# Create the (wrapper) class and define all functions which will be available in Python after
# See the header file of the DLL to have the declaration of all functions available
class ImageProcessingDll(object):
    def __init__(self):
        mydll.imSmooth.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_int, c_int, c_int, c_int, c_int]
        mydll.imSmooth.restype = POINTER(c_ushort)

        self.obj = mydll.AllocateHandleImg()

    def imSmooth(self, ptrImg, width, height, inputType, kernelWidth, kernelHeight):
        return mydll.imSmooth(self.obj, ptrImg, width, height, inputType, kernelWidth, kernelHeight)

# Then call this function
handle = ImageProcessingDll();
ptrImg = handle.imSmooth(someImage.__array_interface['data'][0], someImage.width, someImage.height, someImage.type, 2, 2)

# Create image from pointer received by the DLL
imgrecreated = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(cast(ptrImg, POINTER(c_uint16)), shape=(self.img.shape)).copy()
```

And in C++ I have:

```
unsigned short * myClass::imSmooth(void *ptrImg, int width, int height, int inputType, int kernelWidth, int kernelHeight)
{
    // imgResult (Mat object) is a class Variable so the result is not temporary and freed at the end of the function call

    // Get image and reshape it as Mat object
    Mat imgTemp = Mat(height, width, inputType, (uchar*)ptrImg).clone();

    // Convert if needed
    if (inputType < 5)
        imgTemp.convertTo(imgTemp, CV_32FC1);
    imgResult = imgTemp.clone();

    // Create kernel (normalized matrix)
    Mat kernel = Mat(kernelHeight, kernelWidth, CV_32FC1, 1) / (float)(kernelWidth*kernelHeight);

    // Process filter with my own kernel
    filter2D(imgTemp, imgResult, -1, kernel, Point(-1, -1), (0, 0), BORDER_DEFAULT);

    // Convert to initial type if needed
    if (imgResult.type() != inputType)
        imgResult.convertTo(imgResult, inputType);

    // Return result
    return imgResult.ptr<ushort>();
}
```

Let's see the images without and with shift:

[image: C++ image]
[image: Python image]

I don't know if it comes from my way to recreate an image from a pointer on Python, or maybe some OpenCV function rearrange data and so my Python function works correctly but with data in a different order than usual.

Thank you in advance for any advice/help.

Comment: are you taking into account BGR channel sequence rather than RGB?

Comment: I only work with uint8/16 image so I don't need to.